# print and logger.errors in for loops

Tags: python, django

Is there any reason why a print statement or a logger.error wouldn't print to the command prompt (I'm developing on my local machine) when executed in a for loop?

I've got the following code within one of my views that pertains to a form set. As there are multiple forms to

```
if formset.is_valid():    
   instances = formset.save(commit=False)    
   print ("Im outside the for loop")    
   for instance in instances:
       print ("Im inside the for loop")       
      instance.user = request.user
      ... #other code that successfully runs
```

There is code within the "for instance in instances" loop that I know executes. I commented out the loop and the page breaks. As a result, I'm 100% certain the for loop is being executed 3x (there are 3 forms in the formset), but the print statement "Im inside the for loop" doesn't hit command prompt once. I've tried using logger.error as well with the same result: The 'outside' error prints, but there are no 'inside' errors that print.

I'm baffled on this one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have a extra blank space in that line:   print ("Im insid... , delete it . Also you could print len(instances ) before the loop ;)

Comment: Obviously `instances` is empty even though you think otherwise.